# Computing the number of elements of order $2$ and $3$, in the groups $L_{3}(q)$

Tags: finite-groups

What are the number of elements of order $2$ and $3$ in the groups $L_{3}(q)$?
Also let $r$ be a divisor of $q^2+q+1$. What is the nuber of elements of order $r$ in the groups $L_{3}(q)$?

Comment: Does $L_3(q)$ stands for $\text{PSL}(3,q)$?

Comment: @Easy. Thank you. Yes $L_{3}(q)$ stands for PSL(3, $q$)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.100.7645%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&ei=kMN4UcK8GcaziwL3k4DYDQ&usg=AFQjCNGDKcUhp920XTPSnnQD1ZSxW5p3jQ&bvm=bv.45645796,d.cGE&cad=rja) is a list of the subgroups of $\text{PSL}(3,q)$, hopefully helpful to your question.